# Insert values from a short list into a long list

Tags: python, iterator

The problem I have is that I would like to insert values from a shortlist into a longer list at specific locations so, we have List1 and List2

```
List1 = [10, 20, x, 50, x 100, 20, x] 

List2 = [99, 88, 111]
```

and on the x position in List1, I would like to insert a value from List2 (in the same order).
To get an end result as following:

```
List_result = [10, 20, 99, 50, 88, 100, 20, 111]
```

I have tried to iterate over the different lists however gotten nowhere so far.
I hope someone can help me out!

thank you in advance

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to iterate over the first list and match the element with `x` and replace by the index from the second list:

```
List1 = [10, 20, 'x', 50, 'x', 100, 20, 'x']

List2 = [99, 88, 111]

i = 0
for indx, l1 in enumerate(List1):
    if 'x' == l1 :
        List1[indx] = List2[i]
        i += 1
print(List1)
```

OUTPUT:

```
[10, 20, 99, 50, 88, 100, 20, 111]
```

**EDIT**:

Another way with creating a new list:

```
new_lst = []
for x in List1:
    if x != 'x':
        new_lst.append(x)
    else:
        for y in List2:
            new_lst.append(y)

print(new_lst)
```